# Why are my class methods undefined from NestJS DI stored in a map?

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I created an EventService to store custom events which getting added through a custom decorator. Everything seems to work so far, but the only issue I got is if I try to get the stored event (class) the methods inside are undefined.

The strangest part here is, that the class itself seems to be initialised.

What could be reason for this?

event.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
/**
 * @class EventService
 */
export class EventService {
    /**
     * @private
     * @readonly
     * @type {Logger}
     */
    private readonly logger: Logger = new Logger(EventService.name);

    /**
     * Event Storage
     *
     * @private
     * @readonly
     * @type {Map<string, BaseEvent>}
     */
    private readonly _events: Map<string, BaseEvent> = new Map<
        string,
        BaseEvent
    >();

    /**
     * Add Event
     *
     * @public
     * @async
     * @param {string} key Event Name
     * @param {BaseEvent} event Event Class
     * @param {boolean} overwrite Overwrite Event in Map
     * @returns {Promise<void>}
     */
    public async add(
        key: string,
        event: BaseEvent,
        overwrite = false
    ): Promise<void> {
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
        const className = (event as any).name;
        const hasRegistered = await this.has(key);

        if (hasRegistered && !overwrite) {
            this.logger.error(`${key} already registered with: ${className}`);
            return;
        }

        if (hasRegistered && overwrite) {
            this._events.set(key, event);
            this.logger.log(
                `${key} got overwritten by event class: ${className}`
            );
            return;
        }

        this._events.set(key, event);

        console.log(event);
        console.log(event.test);

        this.logger.log(`${key} was registered to: ${className}`);
    }
}
```

event.decorator.ts

```
/**
 * Bind Event to Class
 *
 * @function
 * @param {string} name Event Name
 * @param {boolean} client Determinate if its a client event
 * @param {string} overwrite Overwrite existing event
 */
export function Event(name: string, client = false, overwrite = false): any {
    return (constructor: any) => {
        return class extends constructor {
            constructor(...args: any[]) {
                super(args);

                const eventService: EventService = this.eventService[0];
                eventService.add(name, constructor, overwrite);
            }
        };
    };
}
```

player-join.event.ts

```
@Injectable()
@Event('playerJoin')
export class PlayerJoinEvent extends BaseEvent {
    /**
     * @private
     * @readonly
     * @type {Logger}
     */
    public readonly logger: Logger = new Logger(PlayerJoinEvent.name);

    /**
     * Handle Player Join
     *
     * @public
     * @async
     * @param {any} player Joining Player
     * @returns {Promise<void>}
     */
    public async execute(player: string): Promise<void> {
        this.logger.log(`${player} joined the server`);
    }

    public test(): void {
        this.logger.debug('hi');
    }
}
```

Console Output

```
[Nest] 22508  - 20.09.2022, 19:44:48     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 22508  - 20.09.2022, 19:44:48     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +24ms
[class PlayerJoinEvent extends BaseEvent] // these both logs are in the EventService.ts after adding them
undefined
[Nest] 22508  - 20.09.2022, 19:44:48     LOG [EventService] playerJoin was registered to: PlayerJoinEvent
```

Answer (score 0):

`event` is the class *reference*. So `event.test` would be looking for the `static` method on the `event`, rather than the instance method. To get the instance `test` method you'd need to either reference it through the prototype (e.g. `event.prototype.test`) or you'd need to pass the instance of the `BaseEvent` not the reference to it